# Wrap Python `str` so that wrap persists across operators

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, inheritance, extend

I wish to "wrap" or extend Python `str`, in order to add a few functionalities dedicated to my problem.

```
class Wrap(str):

     def custom_interface(self):
         pass
```

or

```
class Wrap(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        """initiate with a str
        """
        self._value = value

    def custom_interface(self):
        pass
```

I wish the usual operators and functionalities defined on `str` and returning `str` like `__rmul__` or `join`, *etc.*, do work on `Wrap` and return `Wrap` objects, like:

```
>>> w = Wrap('foo') # wrap any `str`
>>> type(w)
<class 'Wrap'>

>>> t = w * 2 # use a `str` operator on `Wrap`
>>> t
'foofoo'
>>> type(w * 2)
<class 'Wrap'>

>>> j = Wrap('.').join(['b', 'a', 'r']) # use `str` interface on `Wrap`
>>> j
'b.a.r'
>>> type(j)
<class 'Wrap'>

>>> j.custom_interface() # and still enjoy dedicated interface
```

Is there any way I could get this behaviour while avoiding all the boilerplate reimplementation of `__rmul__`, `join`, *etc.*?

Comment: You could try https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit, but they warn that this should **not** be used in production code.

Comment: You may find [`collections.UserString`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserString) useful

Comment: @jonrsharpe haha, I guess I was asking for something too nasty with a general `class` indeed.. actually `str` is enough :)

Comment: @vaultah Subclassing `collections.UserString` does work for `+` and `*` operators, but not for `join`.. how do `__rmul__` and `join` differ?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, but I'm not too sure.

Comment: @vaultah Yeah.. there's not much information [there](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserString) in the end :\